# Can I fade every textblock on button click?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a page in xaml that leads to another page. But I want to make a smooth transition to the other page, so how can i fade every textblock and that page to 0 alpha and the same with one image (logo, Name proptery is "Logo").

I dont want to fade the background as it is the same as in the other screen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good opportunity to get introduced to the wonderful world of Opacity Mask! It can be pretty darn handy, here's a decent [tutorial](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-theme-friendly-UI--in-WP7-using-OpacityMask) that might help get you started. You could just place one over your content and using a storyboard tinker with the opacity properties instead of having to interact with elements individually. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look up StoryBoard animations, specifically DoubleAnimation, and set the targetproperty to Opacity. You can either do this in the Xaml or the codebehind.